# Speeding up Between Search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using MaxMind free databases to do IP lookups. I convert the data to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoBlocks](
    [StartIPNum] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EndIPNumb] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LocationNum] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

There are about 3.5M records in this lookup table.

My goal is to determine the LocationNum for an IP(decimal form) by finding the record where the IP is between StartIPNum and EndIPNum

My stored procedure looks like this:
    Parameter: @DecimalIP bigint

```
select GeoBlocks.StartIPNum ,@DecimalIP as DecimalIp 
     ,GeoBlocks.Postalcode ,GeoBlocks.Latitude as Latitude
     ,GeoBlocks.Longitude as Longitude
     from GeoBlocks
    where @DecimalIP between GeoBlocks.StartIPNum  and GeoBlocks.EndIPNumb
```

I have created unique indexes on StartIPNum and EndIPNum.

However, when I run this, SQL server does a table scan for the Where portion of the query. This query takes 650-750ms. (Most queries on my server take 0-2ms)

How do I speed up this query?

Added Sample Data:

```
StartIPNum  EndIPNumb   LocationNum PostalCode  Latitude    Longitude
1350218632  1350218639  2782113                  48.2000    16.3667
1350218640  1350218655  2782113                  48.2000    16.3667
1350218656  1350218687  2782113                  48.2000    16.3667
1350218688  1350218751  2782113                  48.2000    16.3667
1350218752  1350218783  2782113                  48.2000    16.3667
```

Comment: If you are using IPV4 addresses you can convert them to `BIGINT` values and use an appropriate index. Your "decimal" (?!) values in strings sorted alphabetically may not do what you want. Some sample data, please? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: I tagged with sql-server and tsql. SQLServer is 2014

Comment: @habo I suggest posting the first part of your comment as an answer. I think you're spot on.

Comment: Okay, it looks like your first row of sample data (`1350218632  1350218639`) is IPV4 address range `080.122.179.136 080.122.179.143`. The only problem is that you're storing an integer value in a string field, hence an indexed lookup will work alphabetically rather than numerically ("10" < "2"). changing the columns datatype to `BIGINT` should solve the problem. (Since your `WHERE` clause uses mixed datatypes SQL has to convert one to another. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Each row is converted to `BIGINT`s for comparison each time. Ouch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

To summarize information scattered among various comments:

1. The IP address columns are `VarChar(50)` strings containing decimal values without left padding. An index on those columns will sort them alphabetically, not numerically, i.e. "10" < "2". (With left padding the sort will be correct numerically as well: "10" > "02".)
2. The `WHERE` clause (`where @DecimalIP between GeoBlocks.StartIPNum and GeoBlocks.EndIPNumb`) uses mixed datatypes. `@DecimalIP` is a `BIGINT` while the two columns are `VarChar(50)`. SQL handles operations among mixed datatypes by implementing a data type precedence scheme.  ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).) This causes the IP addresses in each row to be converted from strings to `BIGINT` values, hence the comparison is done numerically and the "expected" results are returned at a considerable cost. The indexes are (all but) useless in this case.
3. Changing the columns to `BIGINT` will allow the use of an index to improve performance and ensure that comparisons are done numerically rather than alphabetically. An *single* index containing both the `StartIPNum` and `EndIPNumb` columns will greatly improve performance. Note that if overlapping address ranges are not allowed then the index will effectively be unique on `StartIPNum` and could be replaced with an index on `StartIPNum` with `EndIPNumb` as an *included column* for performance.

**Original Answer**:

If you are using IPV4 addresses in dotted notation, e.g. "192.168.0.42", you can convert the strings into `BIGINT` values with this UDF:

```
create function [dbo].[IntegerIPV4Address]( @IPV4Address VarChar(16) )
  returns BigInt
  with SchemaBinding
  begin
  declare @Dot1 as Int = CharIndex( '.', @IPV4Address );
  declare @Dot2 as Int = CharIndex( '.', @IPV4Address, @Dot1 + 1 );
  declare @Dot3 as Int = CharIndex( '.', @IPV4Address, @Dot2 + 1 );
  return Cast( Substring( @IPV4Address, 0, @Dot1 ) as BigInt ) * 0x1000000 +
    Cast( Substring( @IPV4Address, @Dot1 + 1, @Dot2 - @Dot1 - 1 ) as BigInt ) * 0x10000 +  
    Cast( Substring( @IPV4Address, @Dot2 + 1, @Dot3 - @Dot2 - 1 ) as BigInt ) * 0x100 +
    Cast( Substring( @IPV4Address, @Dot3 + 1, Len( @IPV4Address ) * 1 ) as BigInt );
  end
```

You can either store the integer values or create an index on a computed column based on the functions result. Note that you need to change your query to reference the integer column in the `WHERE` clause.

If you store the values as integers the following function will convert them back to normalized strings where each part of the address is three digits. These values can be used in comparisons since they will sort the same way both alphabetically and numerically.

```
create function [dbo].[NormalizedIPV4Address]( @IntegerIPV4Address as BigInt )
  returns VarChar(16)
  with SchemaBinding -- Deterministic function.
  begin
  declare @BinaryAddress as VarBinary(4) = Cast( @IntegerIPV4Address as VarBinary(4) );
  return Right( '00' + Cast( Cast( Substring( @BinaryAddress, 1, 1 ) as Int ) as VarChar(3) ), 3 ) +
    '.' + Right( '00' + Cast( Cast( Substring( @BinaryAddress, 2, 1 ) as Int ) as VarChar(3) ), 3 ) +
    '.' + Right( '00' + Cast( Cast( Substring( @BinaryAddress, 3, 1 ) as Int ) as VarChar(3) ), 3 ) +
    '.' + Right( '00' + Cast( Cast( Substring( @BinaryAddress, 4, 1 ) as Int ) as VarChar(3) ), 3 )
  end
```

You could round-trip the string values in your table to get them all into "normalized" form so that they sort correctly by using both functions. Not an ideal solution since it requires that all future inserts and updates be normalized, but it may help for the moment.

Comment: Converting to bigint is not a problem. I can change the table structure to bigint and reimport all the data as bigint. However, what I don't fully understand is whether you are suggesting a create one record for each IP address. Right now, each record represents a range of bigint IP addresses. It would mean 4,294,967,296 records as opposed to 3,500,000 I have now. (I'm new to TSQL!)

Comment: Nope, you can still use address ranges. You can also create a single index that includes _both_ `StartIPNum` and `EndIPNumb`. That should do wonders for performance. (Numb?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the index is not properly set. You can improve it like this:

1. Go into **SQL Server Management Studio**, and open a new query window
2. Select from Menu: *Query->Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl+M)*
3. Type your query and execute it

Now the query will execute, and the execution plan will be displayed. And if the index is bad, it will show you a hint which index is missing and what you can do.

**It will display a precise SQL statement which you need to create the index.**
Just copy + paste that statement and execute it, and then your index should work.

Comment: Thanks HABO. I didn't implement the code you gave, but took your suggestions. 1. I changed the table structure so the IPs are now bigint. 2. I created a clustered index  with both startipnum and endipnum as the index fields. Now the same query that took around 750ms, takes around 150ms. Appreciate everyone's input!

Comment: 150ms is still too slow. BTW, I am not habo ;)