# Picking latest message from a conversation in a messages table

Tags: t-sql

I have a messages table with structure something like this:

```
Messageid auto
FromUserID int
ToUserid Int
ConversationID int
Subject text
Message text
DateSent datetime
MessageRead bit
```

I  need to write a query which return the row (or just the messageid and I can do a self-join) of the last (most recent) message for each conversation. Essentially this means that within a given conversation (represented by conversationid), which of several messages is the latest and what is the messageid of this message.

I can group by conversationid and ask for max(datesent), but then how do I get the messageid for that particular record?

(This is a production db, so I can't modify the table structures.)

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: @HABO  [deja vu...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790081/speeding-up-between-search#comment64950507_38790081).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
( select * 
       , row_number() over (partition by ConversationID order by DateSent  desc) rn 
  from table 
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: The code is very elegant. However, the execution time of 9 minutes is way too long to retrieve a single dataset. Table has 338k messages with 266k unique conversations.

Comment: Maybe you should use indexed view for this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the execution time would be shorter than Paparazzi's... but here is an alternative you can try using an inner join:

```
select t.*
from table t
join (
         select conversationid, max(datesent)
         from table
         group by conversationid

      ) x on x.conversationid = t.conversationid and x.datesent = t.datesent
```